# $_GET or $_POST for SELECT queries

Tags: php, post, pdo, get

Lets say I have a list full of links like this

```
<div>
   <a href="#">Link 1</a>
   <a href="#">Link 2</a>
   <a href="#">Link 3</a>
   <a href="#">Link 4</a>
   <a href="#">Link 5</a>
   <a href="#">Link 6</a>
   <a href="#">Link 7</a>
</div>
```

Using these links I'll replace a full page data, In this case, Do I use `$_GET` or `$_POST` requests while caring about the `Security` and `Performance`. Keeping in mind that I use `PDO` to fetch the data.

Comment: Use whatever works for your application. If you want bookmarkable links, use GET, otherwise use POST.

Comment: <a> tags are not going to be able to POST data afaik

Comment: `#` is not a `POST` nor `GET`. You mention `PDO` and `security` seeing how you plan to use this might be useful.

Comment: If by _I will replace a full page data_ you mean you are using AJAX to get the data you will use to replace the page, you can use either but POST would be my preference, although it is no more secure than GET

Comment: To be honest you dont really provide enough information about what might be going on in your page for any definitive answer

Comment: Security wise it doesn't matter if you GET or POST it, just make sure that where you handle your data that you properly escape it or use prepared statements.

Comment: @RiggsFolly The query that fetches all the data to the website would change to fit the `$_GET` or `$_POST` request and changes all the page.

Comment: @RiggsFolly a simple SQL query to SELECT all the data from a table would be used and changes depending on a main variable set on the `$_GET` or `$_POST` request

Comment: I still dont know if you mean you are just linking to another dynamic page or replacing the current page with data collected with an ajax call

Comment: @RiggsFolly a normal HTML page, All its elements are replaces by variables depending on the fetched row, the request will just change the row number to get the decided row data.

Comment: @JohnConde But people used to say the `GET` is invulnerable more than `POST`, Does the fact that i use `PDO` solves this and make both the same?

Comment: Sorry I am still no wiser

Comment: POST and GET can easily be sniffed unless you are using a secure page `HTTPS:`